# Error en sintaxis, pagina en PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

Tengo un error de sintaxis, pero no lo encuentro
el código de pagina es el siguiente:

```
<title>Datos</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php

       $conexion = new_mysquli("localhost","root","","biblioteca")

       $nombre = trim ($_POST['txtNombre'])
       $cedula = trim($_POST['txtCedula'])
       $carrera = trim($_POST['txtCarrera'])

       $Insertar = "INSERT into TablaBiblioteca values ('$Nombre','$Cedula','$Carrera')"; 
       $resultado = mysquli_query($conexion, $Insertar)
          or die ("Error al insertar los registros");

       mysqli_close($conexion);
       echo "Datos insertados correctamente";
    ?>

</body>
</html>
```

El **error** es el siguiente:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$nombre' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\xampp\htdocs\biblioteca\Datos.php on line 11

Comment: Te faltan los `;`

Comment: Ya agregue los ; y sigo presentando el mismo error

Comment: en las tres variables ya pusiste los `;` ?

Comment: además de eso tienes mal escrita esta función `$resultado = mysquli_query($conexion, $Insertar)` en las dos líneas

Comment: Si bro, ya lo hice como me indicaron y sigo presentando el mismo error

Comment: en la variable `$conexion` tambien te hacen falta

Comment: Es que, al colocarle el ; me aparece el siguiente error Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function new_mysquli() in C:\xampp\htdocs\biblioteca\Datos.php:9 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\biblioteca\Datos.php on line 9

Comment: Es que el nombre de la función es `new mysqli()` no se de donde sacaste `new_mysquli()`

Comment: Porque ese metodo no existe

Comment: los puntos y comas son totalmente necesarios y el error que indicas te genera es por haber escrito mal el nombre como ya te indican

Comment: Es lo que dice @Arreguin92, por eso te da error el trata de buscar esa función `new_mysquli()` pero no existe

Comment: Simplemente acomoda los `;` coloca los nombres de las variables bien cuando las llamas y coloca bien los nombres de las funciones predefinidas

Answer (score 3):

Saludos tal como te comentan tienes diferentes errores:

- Falta punto y coma al final de cada instrucción `;`
- Nombres de   variables distintos a los declarados.
- Es `mysqli` no `mysquli`

Tu código deberia ser algo así:

```
<title>Datos</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php

       $conexion = new mysqli("localhost","root","","biblioteca"); //aqui punto y coma y es mysqli no msquli

       $nombre = trim ($_POST['txtNombre']); //aqui punto y coma
       $cedula = trim($_POST['txtCedula']); //aqui punto y coma
       $carrera = trim($_POST['txtCarrera']); //aqui punto y coma

       $Insertar = "INSERT INTO TablaBiblioteca VALUES ('$nombre','$cedula','$carrera')";  //aqui variables con nombres distintos
       $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $Insertar)
          or die ("Error al insertar los registros");

       mysqli_close($conexion);
       echo "Datos insertados correctamente";
    ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Espero te sirva y suerte..!!

Comment: Hermano muchisimas gracias, ya arreglue mi Base datos perfectamente.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**
Como ya te mencionaron en los comentarios, tu codigo esta lleno de errores, te hacen falta muchos **`;`** aparte de que el nombre de la función **`mysqli`** esta mal escrita, te dejo como debería de quedar:

```
<title>Datos</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php

        $conexion = new mysqli("localhost","root","","biblioteca");

        $nombre = trim ($_POST['txtNombre']);
        $cedula = trim($_POST['txtCedula']);
        $carrera = trim($_POST['txtCarrera']);

        $Insertar = "INSERT into TablaBiblioteca values ('$nombre','$cedula','$carrera')";
        if(!mysqli_query($conexion, $Insertar)){
            die ("Error al insertar los registros");
        }
        
        mysqli_close($conexion);
        echo "Datos insertados correctamente";
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Lo que veo es que tus variables están en **minúsculas**, aparte que les falta su `;`:

```
$nombre = trim ($_POST['txtNombre']);
$cedula = trim($_POST['txtCedula']);
$carrera = trim($_POST['txtCarrera']);
```

Pero cuando las quieres usar, las pones en **mayúsculas**

```
$Insertar = "INSERT into TablaBiblioteca values ('$Nombre','$Cedula','$Carrera')";
```

Tu query debería de ser también en minúsculas:

```
$Insertar = "INSERT into TablaBiblioteca values ('$nombre','$cedula','$carrera')";
```

Comment: Ta lo coloque de esa forma y un nuevo error aparece  Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function new_mysquli() in C:\xampp\htdocs\biblioteca\Datos.php:9 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\biblioteca\Datos.php on line 9

Answer (score -1):

Tienes un typo, estas intentando ejecutar la funcion `new_mysquli` `mysquli_query` y la funcion correcta `mysqli_query`